# Во()избежние(и)

Tags: орфография

Вчера споткнулась об этом слово в предложении "Во()избежание(и) несчастных случаев". Хотелось написать слитно, но Ворд подчеркнул. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно пишется это слово?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ однозначный: во избежание

Answer (score 5):

Это производный предлог, пишется раздельно с буквой **е** на конце, как и в других производных предлогах: в течени**е**, в завершени**е**, вследстви**е** (но "в отношени**и**")

Answer (score 3):

Производные предлоги могут писаться ка слитно, так и раздельно, также они могут иметь конечные гласные Е/И.

Предлоги пишутся раздельно (В ТЕЧЕНИЕ, В ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ, ВО ИЗБЕЖАНИЕ, В ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ), если сохраняется падежное управление с помощью элементарного предлога В.  Фактически мы имеем грамматическое управление "во (избежание несчастных случаев), хотя считаем "во избежание (несчастных случаев)". Если такого управления нет, то предлог пишется слитно. Сравнить: "вследствие дождя" - здесь предлог В не управляет выражением "следствие дождя",  тематика  выражения далеко ушла от начального значения.

Окончание Е соответствует направленному В.п. со значением цели.